# List of Polygons R

Tags: r, r-sp

I have a list of matrices `pl`. In each matrix the first column are longitude coords and the second latitude coords.

```
pl[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -170.7564 -14.36915
[2,] -170.7375 -14.36692
[3,] -170.7564 -14.36915
[4,] -170.7564 -14.36915

pl[[2]]
          [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] 20.00975 39.69194
 [2,] 19.63475 40.13919
 [3,] 19.47862 40.35027
 [4,] 19.38780 40.81030
 [5,] 19.44527 41.12943
 [6,] 19.54308 41.57388
 [7,] 19.47002 41.85503
 [8,] 19.36832 41.84918
 [9,] 19.38110 41.99947
[10,] 19.37669 42.12443
[11,] 19.62082 42.58835
[12,] 19.76418 42.50808
[13,] 19.91584 42.51055
[14,] 20.50891 42.23026
[15,] 20.51831 41.23388
[16,] 20.98332 40.85693
[17,] 21.01053 40.72194
[18,] 20.71082 40.26501
[19,] 20.31834 39.98443
[20,] 20.29611 39.79501
[21,] 20.00975 39.69194
```

From `pl` I am then creating a SpatialPolygons object

```
bound.pol <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(
    list(Polygon(box.sel, FALSE),
    list(Polygon(pl[[1]], TRUE),
         Polygon(pl[[2]], TRUE),
         ....
        ), '0')))
```

where

```
box.sel
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] -180  -90
[2,]  180  -90
[3,]  180   90
[4,] -180   90
[5,] -180  -90
```

is the selected region.

My question is: is there a way to include in the list defining `bound.pol` all the pl without having to include them one by one?

Thanks

Comment: Try `SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(lapply(p1, function(x) Polygon(x, TRUE))), '0'))`

Comment: @akrun  with your code I get   `srl not a list of Polygon objects`. Thanks

Comment: I didn't test the code as the example was not reproducible.

Comment: @akrun thanks I have made it reproducible.

Comment: I tried your code.  It gives the same error.  `Error in Polygons(list(Polygon(box.sel, FALSE), list(Polygon(pl[[1]],  : 
  srl not a list of Polygon objects`